# The Mobius Transformation is a Conformal Mapping.

Tags: complex-analysis

So the Mobius Transformation $S(z) = \dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$ is analytic on its domain $\left\{z \in \mathbb{C} ~|~ z \neq -\dfrac{d}{c}\right\}$

And $$S^{'}(z) = \dfrac{ad-bc}{(cz+d)^2} \neq 0$$ because of the condition $ad-bc \neq 0$, such condition will imply $S^{'}(z)$ is never zero.

Hence $S(z)$ is a conformal map on the $\mathbb{C} \setminus -\left\{\dfrac{d}{c}\right\}$

However, I think the Professor mentioned something that Mobius Transformation is conformal on the whole of $\mathbb{C}$. I do not quite understand where I went wrong with the Theorem.  I follow closely on this theorem:

> If $D$ is an open subset of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, then a function
>   $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a conformal mapping if and only if it is
>   holomorphic (analytic) on its domain and its derivative $f^{'}(z)$ is
>   everywhere non-zero on $D$.

Comment: I think the best way to find out is to ask your professor what he/she meant. What you *think* was mentioned is not necessarily what was said... But if I may guess, it's that they are conformal on the whole *extended* complex plane (i.e., as maps from the Riemann sphere to itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false. Consider the exponential function on a horizontal strip like $D=\{|\Im z|<\pi+\epsilon\}$; it is holomorphic, the derivative never vanishes, but it is not invertible on $D$.
The correct statement is that if a function is holomorphic and the derivative never vanishes, then the function is *locally* conformal.

Comment: So is my solution correct?